# How does the "which -a" command work?

Tags: command-line, search

The `-a` flag in `which` is very useful. However, I'm not sure how it looks for the alternative commands. Can anyone explain this? Does it do a partial string-matching on the command name? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Read the man-page. In a terminal write `man which` ...

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>
>    which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be exe‐
>    cuted in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  com‐
>    mands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching
>    the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.  It
>    does not canonicalize path names.
> ```